# Json response using django 1.8

Tags: json, django, response

I need help in generating json response in the following way using Django 1.8 pl help thanks in advance.

```
{"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am using jquery file upload plugin to upload file using django 1.8 as backend.
I need to generate response in above format.
following is my code However I think there is some mistake
result = []
        result.append({"name":filename,
                       "size":file_size,
                       "url":file_url,
                       "thumbnail_url":thumb_url,
                       "delete_url":file_delete_url+str(my_file.pk)+'/',
                       "delete_type":"POST",})
response_data = JsonResponse(result, safe=False)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Json Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865099/django-json-response)

Answer (score 3):

Hm, do it like described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
data = {"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]}
return JsonResponse(data)
```